# Invoking bundle.js built via webpack from create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, widget, create-react-app

I have created a bundle.js file with webpack from my create-react-app project as it sits with the below config:

```
const path = require("path")
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin")
const glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "release/bundle.min.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
}
```

And, this is my index.html

```
<html>
  <body id="root">
  <script src="path-to-bundle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

But, I dont see anything mounted inside #root. Basically the script does not fire. I tried the `var` and `EntryPoint` webpack config as well. In that case, EntryPoint is always an empty object.

UPDATE:

Package.json

```
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "npm run build:react && npm run build:bundle",
    "build:react": "react-scripts build",
    "build:bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
```

Comment: You _**cannot**_ use custom webpack config with Create React App unless you run _eject_ (which is one-way action).

Comment: @hindmost I followed this and the thread says its possible: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365#issuecomment-376546407

Comment: Here we go! Can you tell me what steps did you try to reproduce it? Can you share with me your steps? Create a new create react app and paste the update in package.json as well as create a new webpack.config.js and share the bundle file with me.

Comment: The first troubleshooting step I would do is to paste `path-to-bundle.min.js` into browser's navigation bar and see if the bundle can be downloaded. That's to check if the webserver is actually serving the bundle or not.

Comment: @winwiz1 I have troubleshooted most of the trivial issues and everything works fine on that end. The only problem is, the bundle code just does not invoke the main method